# Why is material ui build so big

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, code-splitting

I'm trying to get Material-ui to tree-shake correctly. The bundle is extremely large compared to what I'm actually using. I'm not using most of the components listed by the analyzer plugin below and I'm importing everything like it says on the material-ui docs. For example here is what it looks like in one of my files.

```js
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
```

- Parsed: 1.7mb
- Stat: 1.1mb
- Gzipped: 253kb

In contrast, I use react-bootstrap in a very similar way and its size is much smaller.

- Parsed: 55kb
- Stat: 28kb
- Gzipped: 7kb

[image]

Here is my webpack file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const fs = require('fs');
const WebpackOnBuildPlugin = require('on-build-webpack');
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

const buildDir = './build/';

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
  },
  entry: {
    build: './src/index.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 25,
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    chunkFilename: '[id].[contenthash].chunk.js',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
  },
};
```

I thought that Material-UI would be pretty small (in the kb range) given that I'm using basic functionality.

Also, I'm also using code-splitting by route, but Webpack includes MUI in the main bundle because it's shared by a few chunks. That means that I have an extra mb in every route even if that page doesn't use material ui. Is there any way to code-split so only the individual MUI modules get loaded in their appropriate routes?

Comment: A common fix to similar tree-shaking issues is to create a "proxy" component that imports and re-exports the material-ui dependencies that you need only in specific lazy-loaded routes.

Comment: Another thing to check: are you reaching the chunk max?

Comment: Yeah I removed the max chunks but it still includes MUI in the main entry build. I'll try the proxy, that sounds like a good workaround thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this happens with material-ui when you build in development. The production build tree-shakes correctly. Weirdly though, material-ui's own docs claim that if you do the direct file import, the dev build should tree-shake correctly too.